# Cronjob does not work

Tags: java, linux, bash, cron

I tried to set up a cronjob on my server. Actually this command should execute a java programm every hour. But somehow this didn't worked. I googled and tried to set up a test-script that should run every minute so I could see if my cronjob works.

If I execute the script from the shell there is no problem.

```
ps ax| grep cron
```

prints the following

```
1147 ?        Ss     0:00 cron
13940 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

my crontab -l:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
30 * * * * root java -jar -Xss100m /home/crawler/WebCrawler.jar
1 * * * * root /home/crawler/test.sh
```

the test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "this is a test " >> test.txt
```

Does anyone got an idead whats maybe wrong with my system and the crontabs i set up? Its an ubutnu 10.04 server (because the hoster I use got problems with his virtualization and due to that 10.04 is the only version that runs the jvm properly :/)

Comment: Do you know what `-Xss` parameter stands for? :)

Comment: Did the `test.sh` cron execute as expected. I  guess you need to remove the `root` word from the start of command. Never seen that before.

Comment: iirc `-xss` set a stack size for the thread. `test.sh` execute as expected if I start it from the shell with `./test.sh`. I removed the root from the crontab but it still does not execute.

Comment: can you check your mails? I mean enter mail in unix/terminal and check if there are any mails, in it. If there is check what does it say?

Comment: Alright. Totally forgott that cron spams my mail if it got errors. Cron seems to not have problems with executing the `test.sh` because there is no mail mentioning this file. But it got problems with the java command. It feels like the cronjob is not executing the process in the `/home/crawler/` directory. The crontab is unable to find the COnfig.cfg the java programm needs and which is in then `/home/crawler/` directory and it is not able to execute casperjs which ia dded to the path via my bashrc. Some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the word 'root'. It should look like this:

```
1 * * * * /home/crawler/test.sh
```

That should work, if the user that runs cron has enough privileges to run the script.

Comment: Alright. I already tried this. But it seems that the crojob is not executed in the directory the script ist, therefore I'm unable to find the output.

Comment: I think by default Crontab runs from your home directory. But I'm not sure. You can fix it anyway by specifying the output in the script with a full path: `echo "this is a test " >> /tmp/test.txt` or by doing a cd before the cron command: `1 * * * * cd tmp && /home/crawler/test.sh` or doing the cd as the first command in your script, and then the echo statement.

Comment: somehow neither `1 * * * * cd /home/crawler& && test.sh` nor inserting `cd /home/crawler/` into the test.sh seesm to work :(

Comment: And the users that runs crontab can execute the script? 
p.s. You realize this makes it run once an hour right? (1 * * * *). I don't know how you are testing this but you didn't wait an hour before posting here again ;-).

Comment: alright ... I think i mixed up a lot of thinks :D 0-59 works fine with  `cd /home/crawler& && test.sh`. Thank you very much for helping me this morning :)